# Actionscript export problem

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have an actionscript file that I am trying to export from Adobe Flash Builder 4. The program reads in a json.txt file. It works fine when I run it and view it in a browser. I then right-click on the .as file, and choose 'export' -> 'release build' and save it on my computer.

Then, when I open up the .html file, it can no longer load the json file. I have this json file stored online, in a publicly accessible place (a `http://` site), and can reach it from my browser.

Are there any particular things I need to look out for when doing this? For example the web address is

```
"http://web.asdf.edu/rdw/Public/data/dq3.json.txt"
```

Is it possible that this is too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't access the server from here, but it's quite possible you can't load it because it doesn't have a [cross-domain policy file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) (like [Flickr](http://api.flickr.com/crossdomain.xml) does, for example). Server contents are not accessible then.

If that's the case, you'd be still able to test because the standalone player will load the data on local tests, but then it won't work in a browser.

Comment: Is it possible for me to add the domain policy to the folder where I host it? Or is this a system level policy (The link I put in the question is almost identical except I obfuscated it for privacy)

Comment: I played around with settings on a different server and got it to work. Thank you!